# CakePHP 3 uses session cookie from CakePHP 2 for login

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies

I wonder how this could be done. I have 2 apps, let's say:

- example.com (CakePHP 2)
- app.example.com (CakePHP 3)

User will be required to log in through `example.com`, and will then be automatically logged into `app.example.com`. My current solution is configuring the session cookie on the former app to use a wildcard domain, making it available for the latter app. From there, I think I should be able to somehow "copy" the value of the first app's cookie (and settings, etc) to the second app's cookie.

However, I can't seem to be able to read the cookie of `example.com` from `app.example.com` using `$this->Cookie->read()` function.

This is the screenshot of the cookies from 2 sites. I'm trying to get `BravierApp` cookie to have such value that it allows the AuthComponent to give the user a "pass" (with the expiry date the same as `Bravier` cookie.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

**EDIT**

Session Cookie configurations for CakePHP2 and CakePHP3 respectively.

```
// CakePHP 2
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'Bravier',
    'timeout' => 60,
    'cookieTimeout' => 60,
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
        'session.cookie_httponly' => true,
        'session.cookie_secure' => false
    ]
));

// CakePHP3
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'BravierApp',
    'timeout' => 60,
    'cookieTimeout' => 60,
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_domain' => str_replace('app', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),
        'session.cookie_httponly' => true,
        'session.cookie_secure' => false
    ]
]
```

From the CakePHP2 app, the user login session is being recorded by the AuthComponent (by default, I don't change anything there). However, I do update the settings before it saves the session in order to alter the cookieTimeout value.

```
 Configure::write('Session', array_replace_recursive(Configure::read('Session'), [
                    'cookieTimeout' => $cookieExpiryMins,
                    'timeout' => $cookieExpiryMins,
                    'ini' => [
                        'session.cookie_lifetime' => ($cookieExpiryMins * 60),
                        'session.gc_maxlifetime' => ($cookieExpiryMins * 60),
                    ]
                ]));

                $this->Session->destroy();

                $this->Auth->login([
                     'id' => $user['User']['id']
                ]);
```

Now I just wonder how I could log the user in on the CakePHP3 app automatically, with the expiry date set from the CakePHP2 app.

Comment: First things first, do not try to read session cookies via the cookie component, read them from the request object instead (`$this->request->cookie('Bravier')`). That being said, there should be no need to fiddle with the session cookie manually, the CakePHP 3 app should be able to pick up the `Bravier` session just fine as long as its properly configured. That being said, you'll need to supply more details in order for someone to be able to help you further, like, is the cookie being sent in the first place?, what does the configuration (session and auth) look like?, etc...

Comment: Thanks @ndm, more details provided.